# get the rows of a table in 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have first table (the count of rows are varibale) and I want to create the second table. what is the efficient way?
[image]

Comment: why would you want that ? or at least explain more please...

Comment: I want it for a report

Comment: You hade to describe the problem! How are we supposed to understand when you just say "I want it for a report"? I see no pattern in the wanted output...

Comment: The *efficient* way is to do this in your client instead of in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to bring your data to a more '*friendly*' format:

```
;with 
data as
(
    -- replace this with your select
    select * from 
    (
        VALUES ('1', 'a', 'b'),
               ('2', 'c', 'd'),
               ('3', 'e', 'f')
    ) as data(aa,bb,cc)
    --------------------------------
),
dataAsXml as
(
    select CAST(STUFF((SELECT '<i>' + d.[aa] + '</i><i>' + d.[bb] + '</i><i>' + d.[cc] + '</i>' FROM data d FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'') as XML) as data
),
dataAsList as
(
        select  x.i.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as 'Ord',
                x.i.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS 'Value'
        from    dataAsXml
                CROSS APPLY [data].nodes('//i') x(i)
),
normalized AS
(
    select
        case (Ord - 1) % 3 + 1
            when 1 then 'aa'
            when 2 then 'bb'
            when 3 then 'cc'
        end  + cast((Ord - 1) / 3 + 1 as varchar(10)) as columnName, --fix here
        value
    from dataAsList
)
select * from normalized
```

In the query above you can plug in your data in `data` CTE to see the result.
The output will have two columns one that stores your column names and one with values.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/24072)

From here you have to use a dynamic query where you pivot the obtained table `for columnName in` the list of all the column names. I won't describe this process because it has been done many times. Take a look at this answer:

[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931734/1071960)

Note:
I didn't tested the performance of this method with large sets of data but
from some points of view it's efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I pivoted each of the columns then join them together in one row.

```
SELECT aa1,bb1,cc1,aa2,bb2,cc2,aa3,bb3,cc3 FROM
    (SELECT 1 id,[2]aa1,[3]aa2,[4]aa3 FROM(SELECT aa FROM tablea) AS A
    PIVOT(SUM(aa) FOR aa in([2],[3],[4])) AS pvt) A 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 1 id,[400]bb1,[200]bb2,[500]bb3 FROM(SELECT bb FROM tablea) AS A
    PIVOT(SUM(bb) FOR bb in([400],[200],[500])) AS pvt) B ON A.id=B.id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 1 id,[20]cc1,[25]cc2,[20]cc3 FROM(SELECT cc FROM tablea) AS A
    PIVOT(MIN(cc) FOR cc in([20],[25])) AS pvt) C ON B.id=C.id
```

Comment: then do it using t-sql.